# How FAT16 worked on a 16 GB thumbdrive flawlessly?

Tags: partition, fat

So, I created a FAT16 partition in the following way

1. I plugged in my 16 GB thumbdrive.
2. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX count=1`
3. Opened up cfdisk for simplicity.
4. Selected dos label type
5. Created new partition of type "FAT16 <32M"
6. Written the changes to the partition.
7. `mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdXY`

I am surprised to see that it really worked well! So well that I have more than a GiB of data into it right now. My question is how does FAT16 is able to copy that much data? Is there any chance of losing the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you didn’t specify a FAT size with `mkfs`’ `-F` option, it chose the appropriate size for your partition’s *size* (in your case,  FAT32). [mkfs.vfat](https://manpages.debian.org/dosfstools/mkfs.vfat.8) doesn’t care what partition type you selected in `fdisk`.